# How to create Copy to Clipboard?copy data from h1 tag to input (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my App I have h1 tag where data is coming from API. I wanted to copy the h1 data and paste in input field. How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: show some code!

Comment: Do you want to copy to the user's clipboard? Or just have the same text in the input as in the h1?

Comment: In the app I have cards when you click on card it opens the modal and in every modal, it has a heading - user name (different username for every modal)
Wanted to copy the username from Modal heading to  input box(different Page)

Answer (score 0):

1. First install Copy to Clipboard library.https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-copy-to-clipboard.
2. Then make a state for heading and Copy.

   ```
   state = {
    heading: '',
    copied: false,
   };
   ```
3. Call Your api and save the state in the heading.

   ```
   componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('apiurl')
   .then((response) =>{
    // handle success
    this.setState({heading:response.value})
   })
   }
   ```
4. Show the state inside the heading tag.and add the copy to clipboard button to copy whatever is inside the heading state.

   ```
     <h1>{this.state.heading}</h1>

        <CopyToClipboard text={this.state.heading}
          onCopy={() => this.setState({copied: true})}>
          <button>Copy to clipboard with button</button>
        </CopyToClipboard>
   ```
5. Last but not least show it inside `<input />`

   ```
    <input type="text" value={this.state.copied ? this.state.heading :null} />
   ```